# Visual basic ICMP Pinger?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, network-programming, ping, icmp

I am building an ICMP Pinger in visual basic.
I would like to be able to determine the destination address, time out, size of packets, and how many packets to send.

I only have a small amount of programming knowledge, does anybody have any suggestions? Or a more efficient way to run the program?

Here is what i have that is working so far.

---

Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

```
Private WithEvents bwPing As New BackgroundWorker
Private pingTarget As String
Private pingsize As Integer
Private numOfpings As Integer
Dim timeout As Integer

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' start pinger
    bwPing.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    bwPing.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    pingTarget = TextBox2.Text
    timeout = ComboBox4.Text

    If Not bwPing.IsBusy Then bwPing.RunWorkerAsync()

    If ComboBox3.Text & ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        bwPing.CancelAsync()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("*****!!!!!***** INVALID ENTRY *****!!!!!*****")
        MsgBox(" By failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail. ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf ComboBox3.Text = "" Then
        bwPing.CancelAsync()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("*****!!!!!***** INVALID ENTRY *****!!!!!*****")
        MsgBox(" How many troops are you sending in? ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
        bwPing.CancelAsync()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("*****!!!!!***** INVALID ENTRY *****!!!!!*****")
        MsgBox(" How strong are your soldiers? ", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    Else : numOfpings = CInt(ComboBox3.Text)
        pingsize = CInt(ComboBox1.Text)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ' cancel pinger
    bwPing.CancelAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    ' clear
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ComboBox1.Text = ""
    ComboBox3.Text = ""
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
End Sub

Private Sub bwPing_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwPing.DoWork
    ' ping worker
    Dim worker As BackgroundWorker = CType(sender, BackgroundWorker)
    Dim packet(pingsize) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To numOfpings - 1
        bwPing.ReportProgress(i + 1)
        Dim ping As New Ping
        Dim reply As PingReply = ping.Send(pingTarget, timeout)
        If ComboBox3.Text & ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            bwPing.CancelAsync()
        Else
            ListBox1.Items.Add("You hit " & pingTarget & " in " & reply.RoundtripTime.ToString() & " ms with " & pingsize & " bytes.")
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        End If

        If worker.CancellationPending Then Exit For
    Next

End Sub

    Private Sub bwPing_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bwPing.ProgressChanged
    ' update results
    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = numOfpings
End Sub

Private Sub bwPing_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles bwPing.RunWorkerCompleted
    ' finished
    Me.ListBox1.Items.Add("*!* The battle is over, but not the war *!*")
    bwPing.CancelAsync()

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: ' or this Shell("cmd.exe /k" + TextBox1.Text & " " + TextBox2.Text & " " + ComboBox1.Text & " " & ComboBox3.Text & " " + ComboBox2.Text & " ", AppWinStyle.Hide) was just another way i was trying to build the program. kept it there so i wouldnt lose it